# Can a train be boarding?

Tags: transitivity

When we board a train, ship, or aircraft, we get on it:

> ***I* boarded the plane** bound for London.
>
> ***The ship* was boarded** by customs officials.

When a plane or ship is boarding, it is ready for passengers to get on:

> **Flight BA193** for Paris **is now boarding** at Gate 37.

Is it OK to say *"the train is boarding (the passengers)"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  It is OK and common to say "The train is boarding" just as it is to say the same about a plane.

It would be unusual to say "The train is boarding the passengers" even though this is implied.

Comment: It would be unusual because trains don't board passengers. Train crew members board passengers. ;) (Perhaps it should really be *the train is now being boarded* or *the train is now available to be boarded*. . .)